# ldconfig command reverts to previous library version

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-linking

I've been playing with [this](https://github.com/nategreco/raspicam) library for the Raspberry Pi (Raspian/DietPi - Jessie) and ran into a peculiar situation.  I made some local changes, built, and installed the library like so:

```
cmake ..
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

However later I made a correction to the library then built and installed the library, but did not run the 'ldconfig' command.  I ran my program that uses these dynamically linked libraries and it worked with the updated libraries.

However, I then realized I forgot 'sudo ldconfig' and after executing it, the program was clearly running with the previous library version.  I repeated this several times and had to actually use 'ldconfig -p' to find where the .so files were and delete them so that the next ldconfig would use the latest files, and then the problem was resolved.

Why would 'sudo ldconfig' grab a previous version of these build libraries, and where would it grab them from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your current lib path to etc/ld.so.conf and then run ldconfig again.

Or you can add to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/new/path/newpath